# Dividing the div into square blocks

Tags: javascript, css

i have a div which covers the whole screen now i want to dynamically generate square shaped  Divs within this div just like a maths notebook along with giving alternate color to each square blocks

Comment: Would a simple background image suffice? Or do you actually need zillions of separate squares?

Comment: If you need html elements, a table is a simple solution and I guess it would be as semantically incorrect as those zillions of empty divs.

Comment: @thirtydot yup i am so stupid why this didn't hit in my mind any way thanks :)

Comment: i dont exactly what your looking for but try look at this cool project http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't give you too much because I don't know what you've tried and what specific problems you've encountered, but this'd be the basic idea:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var block = $('<div class="block" />');
    block.addClass('block-' + ((i%2)+1));

    $('body').append(block);
}
```

Have your `.block` div's float left, and set to the size you want them to be, and they'll automatically wrap to the next row. They'll also have either the class `.block-1` or `.block-2`, which you can use to set the alternating colors.

Of course, if a background image, as has been suggested in comments, would meet your needs, than that would perform heaps better :)

Comment: I'm really interested to know how David's solution works; will you see the increase of blocks in motion or will they instantly be generated as you open that specific page? How does this class of -1 and -2 work? is that because i is split into 2 pieces? gene

Comment: @Dan: the change will be instantaneous as the script executes, and it will generate 1000 div elements. Depending on the number you generate, I suppose there might be a visible rendering delay, but hardly at a thousand. There's no animation or anything going on, though. `i%2` gives the [modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) of `i` and 2, i.e. the remainder of `i` when divided by 2. The result will always be 0 (`i` is divisible by 2) or 1 (`i-1` is divisible by 2, remainder is 1). Add 1 to that, to get `block-1` and `block-2`, alternating. [Demo](http://jsbin.com/usuyog/1/edit)

Comment: The `float: left` will have the blocks align side by side. You could have done equally well with `display: inline-block`. To get a chess-board like display, you will have to adjust the size of the blocks (or the container) so that the blocks will wrap after an odd number, otherwise they'll appear as straight lines across the page. (In the demo in my previous comment, you can resize the output window to see that in action)